# Why am I getting a "column <x> of relation <y> does not exist" error when running a model in dbt but not when running in a SQL client?

Tags: amazon-redshift, dbt

##### Issue

We have an incremental model that's been running in our nightly production job for months (SQL below). Last week, after upgrading our production environment to `v0.21.0` (from `v0.19.0`), the model began throwing this error:

```
Database Error in model my_model (path/to/my_model.sql)
  column "alias6" of relation "my_model" does not exist
  compiled SQL at target/run/path/to/my_model.sql
```

```sql
{{-
  config(
    materialized = 'incremental',
    dist = 'alias3',
    sort = 'dates_pk',
    unique_key = '__surrogate_key',
    )
-}}

with calculate_metrics as (

    select        
        field1 as dates_pk,
        field2 as alias2,
        {{ my_macro('field3') }} as alias3,
        field4 as alias4,
        field5,
        field6 as alias6,
        field7 as alias7,
        field8 as alias8,
        field9 as alias9,
        (field8::float / field6)::decimal(18, 6) as alias10,
        (field9::float / field7)::decimal(18, 6) as alias11,
        {{ dbt_utils.surrogate_key([
            'field1', 'field2', 'alias4', 'field5']) }} as __surrogate_key
    from {{ ref('upstream_model') }}
    {% if is_incremental() -%}
    where dates_pk >= coalesce((select max(dates_pk) from {{ this }}), '2000-01-01')
    {%- endif -%}

)

select * from calculate_metrics
```

##### What I've tried so far

- `prod env, v0.21.0`. Since the error looked similar to what happens when the schema of an incremental model changes (which it didn't), I did `dbt run -s my_model+ --full-refresh`. Got the same error.
- `dev env, v0.21.0`. Dropped my `dev` schemas, ran `dbt clean && dbt deps`, and alternately did `dbt run` and `dbt build`. Failed on the same model.
- `dev env, v0.21.0`. Tried `dbt build -s my_model --full-refresh`; no luck.
- I ran the compiled SQL from the `target/` directory in Redshift from a SQL client. Did **not** get an error.
- `dev env, v0.19.0`. Downgraded my `dev` env and ran the model lineage from scratch. Failed on the same model. This threw me; I really suspected the upgrade.
- `dev env, v0.19.0`. Changed the model materialization to `table` and ran the model lineage from scratch in `dev`. Got the same error.
- `dev env, v0.19.0`. Pared the code way back to see if I could do anything to get it to run. This, at least, threw a slightly different error.

```sql
{{-
  config(
    materialized = 'table',
    )
-}}

with calculate_metrics as (

    select        
        field1,
        field2,
        {{ my_macro('field3') }} as alias3,
        field4,
        field5,
        field6,
        field7,
        field8,
        field9
    from {{ ref('upstream_model') }}

)

select * from calculate_metrics
```

```
Database Error in model my_model (path/to/my_model.sql)
  column "dates_pk" of relation "my_model" does not exist
  compiled SQL at target/run/path/to/my_model.sql
```

So `dbt` seems to be running some db operation that's looking for aliases that were *previously* in the model, but aren't now. Not sure why that would be, with a `table` materialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some sleuthing by the dbt support team, we discovered the cause of this issue.

The YML docs file for the model contained a column name not found in the model (see sample YML below), and [dbt's `persist_docs` feature](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/persist_docs) had recently been enabled for the model.

```yaml
models:
  - name: my_model
    columns:
      ...
      # This should have been named alias6, but was not updated 
      # when the model changed at some point in the past; this
      # didn't cause an error until persist_docs attempted to
      # `comment` on the (non-existent) field in Redshift
      - name: field6
        description: Foo bar baz.
```

A more specific error message would have helped get to the bottom of this quicker, so I logged [this issue](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/4151) on the dbt-core Github.